# How can I get first 100 values from database and next 100 and so on?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

I have a simple database to store some emails, Is there any way to get the emails from the database in groups of a 100 emails ???

Here is the database structure

```
Table structure for table `emails`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emails` (
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The ideal outcome would be to get the first 100 emails, do something and later get the next 100 and do something else.

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: This is called "paging" or "pagination". Make sure the result is not invalidated between fetches -- use ORDER BY to ensure result stability and prevent deletion or insertion of "handled rows" during the process (or handle the changes accordingly).

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for the help, but, an example would be great since my knowledge about mysql is poor Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LIMIT 100
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id827984

Then for the next one, `LIMIT 100, 100`, and then `LIMIT 200, 100`, and so on.

The first number (when there are two) is the offset.

Comment: To add to this you may want to add an `ORDER BY` on a field that makes the most since so the results for each page are predictable.

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for the help, but, an example would be great since my knowledge about mysql is poor
Thanks again

Comment: Thanks to all I got it, Brad- Thanks for the link

Comment: You also want to make sure that you are using an index on the `ORDER BY` column - see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL [`LIMIT <offset>, <row_count>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) syntax to paginate via SQL.

Assuming that you are going to be displaying these results on a webpage, I'd also recommend that you use a PHP library like [`PEAR::Pager`](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) to help you out here as well. There is a good tutorials [here](http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/).

One thing to note, for performance reasons, you should ensure that you are using `ORDER BY` in your paginated query and that you are using an index. The MySQL Performance blog has a good [explanation](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/).